# Flexible CSS triangles?

Tags: css

I want to add triangles onto the sides of a block to shape it into an arrow [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlyOf.png). But it needs to be flexible and adapt to different lengths of text. I'm thinking that the traditional css-triangles-made-from-borders technique isn't going to work, but that's all I've got so far ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C8TSa/)). Does anyone else have a more robust solution?

Cutting-edge css is fine as long as it degrades nicely.

Comment: If CSS3 is ok, can't you just make the whole thing a background image and use the `background-size` property accordingly to make it stretch?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. I'd rather avoid using images if possible, and I worry that stretching it too much will make it fuzzy, but this may be the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best compatibility solution would be http://dabblet.com/gist/3184227

It uses just pseudo-elements and CSS [**`transform`s**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) (so it works in IE9 and it may be adapted to IE8, where the pseudo-elements could be skewed using a [**matrix `filter`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx) - I've never checked whether that actually works... I only know that gradient filters don't work on pseudo-elements).

The idea is really simple: use two pseudo-elements, each having half the `height`, absolutely `position` them, one taking up the upper half and the other one the lower half and finally `skew` them in opposite directions.

HTML:

```
<div class="t">
    <p>Add text to see how it scales</p>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.t {
    position: relative;
}
.t:before, 
.t:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
}
.t:before {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: skewX(10deg);
}
.t:after {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
}
```

It can be done without pseudo-elements, using just CSS `gradients`. Unfortunately, [IE9 does not support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

Comment: That is really sexy, thanks very much! I hadn't considered css gradients as a fix to this either, but your primary solution makes more sense to my feeble brain.

Comment: @froderik It does work in Chrome, but not unprefixed yet - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d You need to add the `-webkit-transform` version ***before*** the unprefixed one. My demo does not include any prefixes because it uses **`-prefix-free`** http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/ which adds the prefixes as needed.